# How to check mobile app is installed or not in device by sending a link to the user in SMS

Tags: android, ios, azure-mobile-services

i have a use case below can anyone suggest the solution.i need device UUID AND OS version.

"Server will send an SMS to the user's device that requests the user to click a link to return information about the capablity of the device to run the mobile app, and whether the app is installed on the device — if the app is NOT currently installed on the device, the user will be presented with a request to downloaded the app from the appropriate app store. Sending the SMS  will be handled via Microsoft Mobile Services from the server application.

Comment: From my brief research I don't think is possible using a web page, as its not possible to call any android API functions from a normal browser. So far I'm thinking that the the link in the sms needs to install a small app to check the device, or just install the app regardless.

Comment: What you want isn't possible, firt of all, you can't send buttons by SMS.

Answer (score 0):

I can not understand your excat requirement but i am sure you want installed application list that you can get from below code.

we can get the list of Installed  Application.

```
NSDictionary *cacheDict;

NSDictionary *user;

static NSString *const cacheFileName = @"com.apple.mobile.installation.plist";

NSString *relativeCachePath = [[@"Library" stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"Caches"] stringByAppendingPathComponent: cacheFileName];

NSString *path = [[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"../.."] stringByAppendingPathComponent: relativeCachePath];

cacheDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile: path];

user = [cacheDict objectForKey: @"User"];
```

user Dict will give us all the information about installed Application.

Answer (score 0):

Why not send a link that opens in web browser? Then on the server side detect what type of device it came from and then redirect to the relevant store.

Comment: that's good idea but i need device's UUID, OS version on server side.how it's possible